# Concat Object Values from Key with Comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, concatenation

I have an array of objects like below:

```
let modifiers = [
 {name: "House Fries", price: "2.00"},
 {name: "Baked Potato", price: "2.50"},
 {name: "Grits", price: "1.50"},
 {name: "Nothing on Side", price: "0.00"}
]
```

And I want to concat the name of each object inside the above array with a comma. The end result I want is:

```
"House Fried, Baked Potato, Grits, Nothing of Side"
```

How can I achieve that in typescript? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this using `Array.prototype.map()` method. First get all the names using map method and then use `Array.prototype.join()` method to get the comma separated string.

```js
const modifiers = [
  { name: 'House Fries', price: '2.00' },
  { name: 'Baked Potato', price: '2.50' },
  { name: 'Grits', price: '1.50' },
  { name: 'Nothing on Side', price: '0.00' },
];
const ret = modifiers.map((x) => x.name).join(', ');
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. A map function!